# Backreference to entire nested regex

Tags: regex

I have a regex of `((.*)\n)*?stopcondition`

The aim of this regex is to match a number of lines until the stop conditions and then to replace the stopcondition.

For example

```
a
b
stop condition
```

becomes

```
a
b
changed condition
```

Another example:

```
a
b
c
d
stop condition
```

becomes

```
a
b
c
d
changed condition
```

The issue I'm having is using a nested back reference to all the lines captured before the stop condition.

I've currently resorted to writing 2 regex's to handle the case of 2 lines before and 4 lines before.

Is there some syntactic sugar I'm missing to get a reference to the entire match?

If I use a standard $ back reference in this situation it will just match the end last line found before the stop condition.

Comment: Please add a language tag.

Comment: I'm using perl but I am not language specific any that can achieve this is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
^((?:.|\n)*\n)stop condition
```

(replace with: `$1changed condition`)
This looks for the beginning of a line, followed by any number of characters or newlines, and then a newline and a stop condition. The inner group is a non-capturing group (`(?:stuff)`) because we only care about capturing the whole chunk of stuff that came before.

If you don't care about starting at the beginning of a line and the stop condition being on its own line you can use the slightly simpler

```
((?:.|\n)*)stop condition
```

Although if `stop condition` is a unique string that appears nowhere else in the file, you could just do a straight search and replace for `stop condition` and `changed condition`.

Comment: Brilliant! I see why those capture groups are useful now.

Comment: Aw, you're making me blush! Glad I could help. If this worked make sure to mark it as the correct answer for posterity.

Comment: Also, a nice way to build and test our regexes is regexr.com - especially useful when you're learning because you can hover over any character and see what it matches.

Comment: @IanWatson, You should accept this answer if it resolves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine what this says `((.*)\n)*?stopcondition`.

This will match anything before `stopcondition` no matter *what* it is !!

So, `((.*)\n)*?` is totally *useless* since engines always match the first
available (left to right in the source) regex specified literal.

Even if it were to contain something that *needs* to be before `stopcondition`
it is just being replaced without any modification.

In that case, since you're using Perl, use the `\K` construct.
(*Note- some other engines that use PCRE or it's style have this construct

along with it's brother's (*SKIP)(*FAIL)* )

Definition:
`\K       Keep the stuff left of the \K, don't include it in $&`

The *stuff* is consumed, but not part of the match.
This insures you're matching the right `stopcondition` but doesn't include
the matched stuff before it.

Find:  `((.*)\n)*?\Kstopcondition`
Replace:  `changedcondition`

Analyze this `((.*)\n)*?` now.

```
 (                             # (1 start)
      ( .* )                        # (2)
      \n
 )*?                           # (1 end)
```

Group 1 is overwritten on each quantified pass of `()`*?
so, you only ever see what matched on the the very *last* pass.

In this however,

```
 (                             # (1 start)
      (                             # (2 start)
           ( .* )                        # (3)
           \n 
      )*?                           # (2 end)
 )                             # (1 end)
```

Group 1 is not quantified, and contains the entirety of the accumulation of groups
2 and 3 which are overwritten.

P.S. Get some software that knows how to *format, analyze, test and benchmark*  regex.
regexformat.com